# How to start the Firebase Realtime database emulator with open rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I start the emulator with the following command:

`firebase emulators:start --project my_remote_project_id --only database,functions --inspect-functions`

When I go to the locale console (http://localhost:4001/database), I can see 2 databases:

- my_remote_project_id
- fake-server

When I go to `http://localhost:9000/.inspect/coverage?ns=my_remote_project_id`, I can see that the rules are the ones for my remote project.
When I go to `http://localhost:9000/.inspect/coverage?ns=fake-server`, the rules are open:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
    }
}
```

Because of the rules on `my_remote_project_id` database, I cannot import the json I want to test. I can do it though on the `fake-server` database.
The issue is that the cloud functions get triggered only on the `my_remote_project_id` one, and never on the `fake-server` one.

Am I missing something?

I start the app using `admin.initializeApp()` and exported `export FIREBASE_DATABASE_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:9000"`

I can always remove the rules from the remote project (dev environment) but it's not ideal at all.

Comment: Hi @Nico have you tried to use a different file for the security rules for the emulator? As explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#configure_emulator_suite), you can use a different file for the rules used in the emulator, by configuring it in the `firebase.json`.

Comment: @gso_gabriel thanks a lot, I missed that configuration part. Feel free to add a response and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi @Nico glad to hear it helped! I posted an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you to be able to use different security rules for your emulator, you can use different files. This way, you will have one file for your emulator and one for production, so you don't have to worry in your tests.

You can achieve that by configuring a different set of rules in the `firebase.json` rules of the emulator. You can find more information on how to do it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#configure_emulator_suite).